# Is battery life supposed to go not even a year?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MacBook pro that I got about 10 months ago. It seems like I am already starting to experience battery life issues. I have a charge cycle history of less than once a day since I bought it. I first thought it was too much stuff running in the background, so I put a fresh copy of Ubuntu on it to test that out. It still seems to have a bad life. At full charge, 50% brightness, the battery says 3 hours remaining, but then after a few minutes, it goes to 2 and I get an average of about 2.5 hours. I have appleCare. Is there a problem, or is time just going faster for me and the battery is normally like this? I think the battery said it usually has a good 5 years, and it hasn't been 1 for me. The battery indicator on status bar also never says 100%, and is usually stuck at 95-99 when the green light indicates full. Is this normal? Or do I have a bad battery? Is there a way to test my battery properly?

Here is what the power stats say

[image]

Comment: It's sound like you have a bad battery. As @Buscar said you should have many more cycles before the battery starts to behave like you describe. If I compare to my 3 year old MBP it does have better battery then what you describe. Good that you have appleCare! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is detailed information available about your battery.

Click on Apple (top left)

> About This Mac
>
> More Info
>
> System Report
>
> Power

In the Health information it shows how many cycles you had so far.
I have 142 cycles since Oct. 2012.
The battery should last about 1000 cycles.
If you have a problem please see Apple service.

[image]

Above you see some comparison data (from my MBA)
Running @ 100% brightness, Mail, Firefox, Chrome, WIFI and more, consuming about 1200 mA.
Unfortunately Apple does not show the remaining life as time, so you have to use a [formula](http://ncalculators.com/electrical/battery-life-calculator.htm) to calculate that, but it varies based on usage (mA).

Comment: I gave that information in my answer = October 2012 :)

Comment: I really need my morning coffee. :) So you have about the same usage as @Skyler 440 but not experiencing the problems.

Comment: I added the battery stats to my question. Does this look ok?

Comment: I would say your power consumption is abnormally low (or indicator not correct)? at -30mA ??